# Cocoa Touch - Drag onto button to trigger event

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, drag

Hey all, just wondering what the best way to add this capability was.

I want to be able to press the button normally by doing touchDownInside, but I also want to be able to slide my finger from one button to the next and have the next one trigger.

How can I do that?

Ex:

(-) -> (-)
^Buttons^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement touchesEnded method and check if the touch point is within any of your button's frames..

Comment: Doesn't touches ended only trigger on button release? I'm looking for instant activation as soon as the finger touches the screen, and when you slide your finger around, all the buttons that you touch will trigger.

Comment: in that case you can use touchesMoved and trigger the button action when the touch location enters your button's frames.. only you'll have to make sure the action is being triggered only once as touches moved will be called for each pixel traversed by the touch..